# Does the QNET Amezcua Bio Disc work?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, water

Is the [Bio Disc](http://www.amezcua.com/biodisc.html) medically effective?

The product description says

> Bio Disc is able to redefine and harmonise the energy of water,
>   greatly maximising its positive affect on the human body

Their website says

> [...] numerous independent scientific tests verified the Bio Disc’s
>   ability to positively harmonise energy [...]

Does anyone have any references to these scientific tests?

http://www.amezcua.com/Certifications.html
Check these out for references..

Comment: The fact that the BioDisc website doesn't offer any references should be enough of a clue.  The only way it could "work" is via placebo effect...

Comment: "redefine and harmonize the energy of water"... what the hell does that even _mean?_ Last I checked, water is not an a capella group.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say it doesn't work.

I found this

- [Shared Pathology blog: Biodisc - fraud of the century](http://sharad-pathology.blogspot.it/2010/08/biodisc-fraud-of-century.html)

> "As a scientist, I was astonished. It didn't surprise me that I
>   couldn't find any scientific experiments [Emoto] has performed or any
>   peer-reviewed journal articles that have been published describing
>   controlled studies of Emoto's work. A further search revealed that
>   Emoto's degree was from the Open International University in India,
>   where an M.D. degree costs $500 and a Ph.D. costs $350, no classes or
>   tests required."

and this:

[*Is Masaru Emoto For Real?!! Blog:* Review and analysis of Dr. Masaru Emoto’s
published work on the effects of external stimuli
on the structural formation of ice crystals.](http://is-masaru-emoto-for-real.com/)

> "After the lengthy review of Emoto's research methods and results, I
>   have come to believe that Dr. Emoto is offering pseudo-science to the
>   masses in the guise of defensible research."

And I think this comment by Masaru Emoto is particularly illuminating :

> In fact, in the Maui News interview, Dr. Emoto specifically stated,
>   “I do not require any blind tests on any samples,” but rather he
>   believes that “the researcher’s aesthetic sense and character is the
>   most important aspect when taking crystal photographs.”

Comment: It's a bit late, but can you link Emoto to the Bio Disc?